# How to call Twitter oEmbed API using python requests?

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, python-requests

I am trying to get the JSON response from twitter oEmbed API using python's requests library. The tweet ID that I tried to pass in was `1221064170248065024`. And here's the code that I have used for making a request to the API.

```
import requests

tweet_id = '463440424141459456'
embReqUrl = 'https://publish.twitter.com/oembedurl=https://twitter.com/Interior/status/'+tweet_id
embResp = requests.post(embReqUrl)
```

After that, when I go for checking the HTTP status of my response using `embResp.status_code`, it is giving me a `405` status code. What's the right way to do it?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve used a POST method, but this API expects a GET.

```
embResp = requests.get(embReqUrl)
print(embResp.status_code)  
print(embResp.json())
```